# Display bug for email on Outlook (Microsoft 365) in a table cell

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, newsletter

I'm facing with an issue for several days now.
I'm trying to send an email with a table element but text in cell are not vertically align (only on outlook windows).

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  background-color: #f5f8fa; color: #74787e; height: 100%; hyphens: auto; margin: 0; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-word-break: break-all; width: 100% !important; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; word-break: break-word;">
  <table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
        <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin: 0; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;width: 570px;">

          <tr>
            <td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff2; border-top: 1px solid #edeff2; margin: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
              <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom:0px; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
                <tr>
                  <td class="content-cell" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border: 15px solid #fff;">
                    <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:20px 0;width:100%;margin-bottom:50px">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
                            <tbody style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Spécialité</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">SPRYCEL</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">DCI</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Dasatinib</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Firme</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">BRISTOL-MYERS SQUIBB Korea</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Aire thérapeutique</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Leucémie aiguë lymphoblastique (LAL)</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Classification</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Nouvelle indication</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Décision</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Recommandé</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>




                    <table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                      <a href="localhost" class="button button-blue" target="_blank" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3097d1; border-top: 10px solid #3097d1; border-right: 18px solid #3097d1; border-bottom: 10px solid #3097d1; border-left: 18px solid #3097d1;">En savoir plus</a>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:20px 0;width:100%;margin-bottom:50px">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
                            <tbody style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Spécialité</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">YESCARTA</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">DCI</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Axicabtagene ciloleucel (CAR-T Cell)</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Firme</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Daiichi Sankyo</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Aire thérapeutique</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Lymphome diffus à grandes cellules B (LDGCB), Thérapie génique</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Classification</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Nouvelle entité</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Décision</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Recommandé</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>




                    <table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                      <a href="https://localhost/detail/1141/pmda/" class="button button-blue" target="_blank" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3097d1; border-top: 10px solid #3097d1; border-right: 18px solid #3097d1; border-bottom: 10px solid #3097d1; border-left: 18px solid #3097d1;">En savoir plus</a>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:20px 0;width:100%;margin-bottom:50px">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
                            <tbody style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Spécialité</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">MABCAMPATH</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">DCI</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Alemtuzumab</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Firme</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Sanofi K.K.</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Aire thérapeutique</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Leucémie lymphoïde chronique (LLC)</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Classification</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Nouvelle entité</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 161px;font-weight: bold;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Décision</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #74787e; font-size: 13px;width: 375px;">
                                  <div style="border: 10px solid #fff">Recommandé</div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>


                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>




                    <table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; ">
                                      <a href="localhost" class="button button-blue" target="_blank" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3097d1; border-top: 10px solid #3097d1; border-right: 18px solid #3097d1; border-bottom: 10px solid #3097d1; border-left: 18px solid #3097d1;">En savoir plus</a>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the render on outlook :
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRwJr.png) (I hid some parts to get 30000 characters on stackoverflow)

And the margin between the table and the "see more" button doesn't apply.

Anyone have suggestions ?

Thanks
Jeremy

Comment: Have you tried setting table cell padding and margin to 0?

Comment: Have you tried the <cellpadding> HTML attribute on your `<td>`'s as opposed to the 10px white border on the div's that are in the `<td>`'s? Maybe you can skip using the `<div>`'s in the cells then.